# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_E \cos(nx)d\mu=0$ for any $\mu(E)<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I wonder how to show $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_E \cos(nx)d\mu=0$ for any $\mu(E)<\infty$  Here $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I see on any interval $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_E \cos(nx)d\mu=0$. I wonder if we can build a connection between intervals and the $E$ with $\mu(E)<\infty$?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to close?

Comment: You haven't shown any of your own effort towards the question.

Comment: In addition to your own thoughts towards the problem, you can also talk about where you found this problem. Is there's a reason why you think it's true?

Comment: Hint: think Fourier Series. Specifically the Fourier series for the characteristic function of $E$.

Comment: The problem is when $E$ is unbounded and there you can use the standard trick of cutting it at $[-m,m]$ and letting $E_m$ that intersection and then for any $\epsilon > 0$, finding $m$ s.t. $\mu(E-E_m) < \epsilon/2$, so the integral of $|\cos(nx)|$ is also less than $\epsilon/2$ there (uniformly for any $n$ now) and then indeed using Riemann-Lebesgue by translating $E_m$ into finitely many pieces in $[0,2\pi]$ and considering the (finite) sum of the characteristic functions of those pieces

Comment: What is $\mu$? Is it the Lebesgue measure? Otherwise the answer need not be true.

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a particular case of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the set of all Lebesgue-integrable functions $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ for which $\int f(x)\cos(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Then

1. If $f(x) = \mathbf{1}_{[a, b]}(x)$ is the indicator function of a bounded interval, then it is clear that $f \in \mathcal{H}$.
2. $\mathcal{H}$ is a vector space, i.e., it is closed under scalar multiplication and addition. In particular, $\mathcal{H}$ contains all the step functions.
3. $\mathcal{H}$ is closed under $L^1$-convergence. Before proving this, let us see what conclusion we can draw from this. Since any Lebesgue-integrable functions can be approximated by step functions in $L^1$-norm, $\mathcal{H}$ must contain all the Lebesgue-integrable functions. Therefore, $\mathbf{1}_E$ lies in $\mathcal{H}$ whenever $E$ has finite Lebesgue-measure.

   Now we turn to the proof of the claim. Suppose that $f_n \in \mathcal{H}$ and $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$. Then

   \begin{align*}
   \left| \int f \cos(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x \right|
   &\leq \left| \int f \cos(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x - \int f_k \cos(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x \right| + \left| \int f_k \cos(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x \right| \\
   &\leq \int |f - f_k| \, \mathrm{d}x + \left| \int f_k \cos(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x \right|,
   \end{align*}

   and so, taking limsup as $n\to\infty$ gives

   $$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \int f \cos(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x \right| \leq \int |f - f_k| \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

   But since $k$ is arbitrary and the limsup is independent of $k$, letting $k \to \infty$ shows that this limsup vanishes, hence $f \in \mathcal{H}$.
4. If OP is not exposed to the notion of $L^1$-convergence, still we can implement the above idea to the case of $\mathbf{1}_E \in \mathcal{H}$ for $E$ with $\mu(E) < \infty$.

   Indeed, by Step 2, $\mathcal{H}$ contains $\mathbf{1}_{F}$ whenever $F$ is a union of finitely many bounded intervals. But if $E$ has finite Lebesgue-measure, then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a finite union $F$ of bounded intervals such that $\mu(E \triangle F) < \epsilon$. Here, $E \triangle F = (E\setminus F)\cup(F\setminus E)$ is the symmetric difference. Now the trick is that this measure admits the representation

   $$\mu(E \triangle F) = \int \mathbf{1}_{E\triangle F}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int |\mathbf{1}_E(x) - \mathbf{1}_F(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x$$

   From this,

   \begin{align*}
   \left| \int \mathbf{1}_E(x) \cos(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x \right|
   &\leq \left| \int \mathbf{1}_E(x) \cos(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x - \int \mathbf{1}_F(x) \cos(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x \right| + \left| \int \mathbf{1}_F(x) \cos(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x \right| \\
   &\leq \int |\mathbf{1}_E(x) - \mathbf{1}_F(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x + \left| \int \mathbf{1}_F(x) \cos(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x \right| \\
   &\leq \epsilon + \left| \int \mathbf{1}_F(x) \cos(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x \right|.
   \end{align*}

   So, letting limsup as $n\to\infty$, we obtain

   $$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \int \mathbf{1}_E(x) \cos(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x \right| \leq \epsilon, $$

   and letting $\epsilon \to 0^+$ proves the desired claim.